# Textarea full of lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any html component or maybe the textarea can be like this?

[image]

I want to make an essay area in my web app. I tried using textbox but he has to click the next textbox or tab to do this. I want it to break automatically if the user reaches the end and move to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwQrz.pngIf you can use html5, you can utilize the `contenteditable` attribute and create a repeated background image and apply it to a div that you use as your essay area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

http://jsfiddle.net/KeTtb/2

Sorry I missed the obvious answer! Which is just to apply the background image to the textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/SwbB3/1

```
textarea {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwQrz.png);
    width:640px;
    height:172px;
}
```

Comment: If I use it in a form how can I get the text inside?

Comment: You would create a hidden textarea element with a name you wish to post `<textarea name="whatever" style="display:none;"></textarea>` then set an `onsubmit` event handler on the form to set the textarea's  innerhtml to the div's innerhtml.

Comment: If I place it inside the div the text will be written inside the textarea?

Comment: Check out the updated fiddle. You will want a textarea inside the form. It doesn't really matter where the div is since its content is not posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses data URIs ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HA6vd/2/))

With this HTML:

```
<textarea placeholder='type your answer here'></textarea>
```

And this CSS:

```
textarea {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-size: 30px auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: What if you type more than the box can hold and you have to scroll?

Comment: The illusion is broken :P

Comment: there is really no way to do this?

Comment: Well there is a CSS property called background-attachment: local (http://jsfiddle.net/HA6vd/3/), or you can make the text area grow with input (see any auto-grow script)

Comment: But the CSS property isn't supported by Firefox at this time.